# php fetch user data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have 2 tables in a MySql database.

Structure:

```
messages
id | content | user_id | time

submessages
id | subcontent | msg_id | user_id | time
```

In the `submessages` table, column `msg_id` is a foreign key, referencing the `id` column in table `messages`.

Now i need to query from php

```
$cur_userID = $user->current_id; // current user id.
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id > '{$_GET['id']}' // problem here
```

How do I query the `submessages` table for `subcontent` that was posted by other users - exlcuding current user?

Meaning anything with a `user_id` equal to `$cur_userID` shouldn't be displayed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the submessage detail, right?  This query would get all the info from the message table, plus all the info from EACH of the sub-messages.  Thus the join.  But it would exclude sub-messages (answers?) that have the same user_id as the messages (questions?).

```
SELECT m.* sm.*
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN submessages sm
  ON m.id = sm.msg_id
WHERE id > '{$_GET['id']}'   // dont know why gt is used here...
  AND m.user_id <> sm.user_id
```

And I ignored all the formatting necessary to put this into PHP, since really the question as I understand it is how should the SQL be written.

As an aside, I don't get the `id > $_GET['id']` section.  It appears that you are asking for all messages created AFTER this message, and you want to find the submessages for thos messages.  I really can't figure out when this is reasonable, but if that is what you want this is a way that should work.  I suspect you want *equals*, not *greater than*.

Answer (score -1):

```
"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id != " . intval($_GET['id']);
```

Comment: Actually, what this appears to do is give all the messages EXCEPT the one you are interested in.  I think "id" is just the id of the message, not the user.

Comment: isn't not equals `<>` in SQL, not `!=`?

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen: In standard SQL, yes.  However MySQL accepts both forms: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/non-typed-operators.html

Comment: But none of the examples use `!=` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal and I've only been using MySQL for some time and I feel like I've only ever gotten error messages when I tried to use `!=`... I still feel skeptical.